# Insert another key and value to Dictionary, after Deleting the previous key in that Place?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orm

I deleted the a key and its value from a dictionary. Now I need to re-insert another key and value into the empty spot.

I have tried checking if it is null or not, but it shows an exception.

```
if (slotCount < capacity)
{
    int index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    { //finding nearest free slot
        if (registration[i] == null)
        {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (index == -1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No space");
    }
    else
    {
        slotCount = slotCount + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter registration and color separated by a space: ");
        regNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        registration.Add(slotCount, regNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("The entered registration number is: " + regNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Allocated slot is:" + slotCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you delete the key, there is no empty slot in a dictionary... what makes you think there is? So maybe i am misunderstanding the problem

Comment: i need to re insert another key and value into the empty spot.

Comment: Dictionary's aren't lists or arrays, they don't have empty spots. Which makes me think dictionarys are not what you need. You probably just want an array

Comment: You could see the storage of a dictionary as a bucket of water. No matter where in the bucket you remove a gallon, the water level just goes down and does not leave an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

There are no empty slots in a dictionary. It is not a fixed-size collection like an array. When you remove an element from the dictionary, it is almost as if it never existed.

If you want to check if the dictionary does NOT contain a key with a certain slot number, then you would do:

```
if(registration.ContainsKey(i) == false)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does this answers OP's question? _If you want to check if the dictionary does NOT contain a key with a certain slot number.._ - Where is this even asked and how would you assume this a question and provide an answer??

Comment: It's in his question and posted code. He has code in a loop that checks to see if a "slot" in his dictionary is null about 6 lines from the top, which he then says is throwing an error (after he deletes that entry). So he appears to be looking for slots that are not present in his dictionary so he can fill it in. I thought it was rather clear.